# Перехват закрытия дочернего окна

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, closeevent

Есть функция `test()` запускающая дочернее окно, экземпляр класса которого называется `tla`. 
Вопрос как перехватить закрытие этого дочернего окна при нажатии на крестик?

Попытка перехвата через создание в функции метода `closeEvent` ничего не дает. При этом закрытие главного окна перехватывается из функции `closeEvent` в классе `MainWindow`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys, os, time


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        ss = MyWindow()
        self.setCentralWidget(ss)
        
    def closeEvent(self, e):
        print("Main close")
        e.accept()
        QtWidgets.QWidget.closeEvent(self, e)
        
        
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.makeWidget()
        
    def makeWidget(self):
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Click button')
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('new window')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.test)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        
    def test(self):
        def getName():
            #...anything doing...
            tla.close()
            
        def closeEvent(tla, e):
                print('closing tla')
                e.accept()
                QtWidgets.QWidget.closeEvent(tla,e)
        
        tla = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=window, flags=QtCore.Qt.Window)
        tla.setWindowTitle('Тест')
        tlavbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lE_key = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить')
        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Закрыть')
        btn2.clicked.connect(getName)
        btn3.clicked.connect(tla.close)
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(btn2)
        hbox.addWidget(btn3)
        tlavbox.addWidget(lE_key)
        tlavbox.addLayout(hbox)
        tla.setLayout(tlavbox)
        tla.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Title')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите какие действия и в каком окне ва хотите сделать, и какой результат вы хотите получать в результате этих действий.

Comment: @S.Nick изменил вопрос под конкретный пример - суть перехват закрытия дочернего окна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно вас понимаю, но попробуйте так:

```
import sys
# ???import os
# ???import time
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

        
class TlaWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None): 
        super(TlaWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window)   
        self.setWindowTitle('TlaWindow')
        self.parent = parent

        self.lE_key = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить')
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.getName)
        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Закрыть')
        btn3.clicked.connect(self.close_TlaWindow)
        
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(btn2)
        hbox.addWidget(btn3)
        
        tlavbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)        
        tlavbox.addWidget(self.lE_key)
        tlavbox.addLayout(hbox)
        
        self.flag_close = False                                    # !!! +++

    def getName(self):
        #...anything doing...
        self.parent.label.setText(self.lE_key.text())
        self.flag_close = True                                     # !!! +++
        self.close()
        
    def close_TlaWindow(self):
        self.flag_close = True                                     # !!! +++
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, e):                                       # !!! +++
        if self.flag_close:                                        # !!! +++
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Click button')
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('new window')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.test)

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)        
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)

    def test(self):
        self.tlaWindow = TlaWindow(self)
        self.tlaWindow.show()
    
    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.tlaWindow.hide()
        print("Main close")
        e.accept()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Title')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**:

> с вашим кодом все нормально, но в вашем коде окно tla является экземпляром класса TlaWindow, фактически он является главным окном хоть технически и запускается из MainWindow. Мне же в моем коде нужно перехватить окно Tla которое, не является экземпляром отдельного класса, а запускается окном ss которое и является экземпляром отдельного класса MyWindow

Я все равно плохо понимаю то, что вы хотите сделать.

Если вам нужно скрыть или показать кнопку закрытия,
более удобно использовать `WindowCloseButtonHint`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

       
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        
        self.makeWidget()
        
    def makeWidget(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Click button')
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('new window')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.test)
        
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)        
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        
    def test(self):
        def getName():
            print(f'##...anything doing...') 
            tla.close()
        '''    
        def closeEvent(tla, e):
            print('closing tla')
            e.accept()
            QtWidgets.QWidget.closeEvent(tla, e)
        '''
        tla = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=window)            #, flags=QtCore.Qt.Window)

        tla.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() 
            & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint                         # !!! +++
            | QtCore.Qt.Window
        )                
        
        tla.setWindowTitle('Тест')
        tlavbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        lE_key = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Добавить')
        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Закрыть')
        btn2.clicked.connect(getName)
        btn3.clicked.connect(tla.close)
        hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(btn2)
        hbox.addWidget(btn3)
        tlavbox.addWidget(lE_key)
        tlavbox.addLayout(hbox)
        tla.setLayout(tlavbox)
        tla.show()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        ss = MyWindow()
        self.setCentralWidget(ss)
        
    def closeEvent(self, e):
        print("- Main close")
        e.accept()
        QtWidgets.QWidget.closeEvent(self, e)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('Title')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда код]

Comment: Я имел в виду другое, в вашем примере tla по сути является основным окном - экземпляром класса. А мне нужно именно как в моем примере перехватить  дочернее окно.

Comment: @Zmiter я вас не понимаю. Основное окно это -  `window = MainWindow()` и показано на первом изображении.

Comment: давайте попробую сформулировать по другому, мне нужно перехватить закрытие дочки дочки(внучки) , именно так как в моем коде. Не создавая для внучки отдельного класса. Т.е. есть MainWindow где в качестве центрального виджета установлен MyWindow и он в свою очередь запускает Tla, но не как экземпляр отдельного класса, а как свой элемент, можно ли перехватить закрытие этого элемента

Comment: @Zmiter я вас не понимаю. Просто запустите мое приложение, не глядя что там написано, выполняйте действия, которые вам надо. После какого действия у меня выполняется не то что вы ожидаете? Опишите что после действия (какого?) вы получаете что-то (приложите изображение), а вы хотели получить/увидеть следующее   (приложите изображение).

Comment: с вашим кодом все нормально, но в вашем коде окно tla является экземпляром класса TlaWindow, фактически он является главным окном хоть технически и запускается из MainWindow. Мне же в моем коде нужно перехватить окно Tla которое, не является экземпляром отдельного класса, а запускается окном ss которое и является экземпляром отдельного класса MyWindow

Comment: @Zmiter я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.

Comment: спасибо! это в принципе позволяет реализовать решение для моей проблемы, не такое изящное как хотелось бы, но работоспособное. Я не сформулировал зачем мне это все надо. При закрытии окна tla не через кнопку "добавить" мне было необходимо провести ряд дополнительных завершающих операций и я надеялся, что получиться реализовать через closeEvent, но теперь устранив фактор кнопки "X", можно повесить необходимые операции на метод запускемый кнопкой "закрыть"